# java static class / variables

Tags: java, static, final

Unsure about static variables.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Logger {
    public static final File log = new File(File.listRoots()[0], "log.log");
    public static void log (String message) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Is the variable `log` pointing to the same memory throughout the life of the program? Basically is the `log` definition `new File(File.listRoots()[0], "log.log")` calculated multiple times or just one, and when?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is invoked once per classloader. Which, normally, means once.

A static variable is initialized as soon as the class declaring it is loaded by the classloader, and stays there until the classloader is destroyed, which in most cases means - at the end of the program execution / application lifecycle.

Comment: what if I access it like `File f = Logger.log` I'm creating a new instance of the class.

Comment: `File f = Logger.log` creates a new reference to the single file that was already instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Just once. AFAIK, when class is loaded.